# How to “group by” multiple variables, eliminating duplicates, with Python pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, group-by, duplicates

I have an input file with this sort of data:

> **> Due big size of input file, i need to take only unique pairs -
>
> > userID-locationID  (some kind of preprocessing)**

```
userID locationID
     1       loc1 
     1       loc2 
     1       loc3 
     2       loc1 
     3       loc4 
     3       loc3 
     3       loc1
```

I have to find how many distinct users are checked on each location and get new column with values. I already tried this but it is not what I need.

```
DataFrame({'count': df.groupby(["userID","locationID",]).size()}).reset_index()
```

Comment: When you say *distinct* users, do you mean that some rows can be duplicates?

Comment: I'm changing your title to *"How to “group by” multiple variables with Python pandas eliminating duplicates"*. Original title didn't have anything like enough information.

Answer (score 3):

This should be what you are looking for, but I'm not sure if there's an easier way:

```
In [5]: df.groupby(['locID','userId']).last().groupby(level='locID').size()
Out[5]: 
locID
loc1     3
loc2     1
loc3     2
loc4     1
dtype: int64
```

Taking the last of each group will remove duplicats

Comment: Due big size of input file, i need to take only unique pairs -
userID-locationID (some kind of preprocessing).
Maybe can create some kind of Set ?

Answer (score 3):

There's a Series (groupby) method just for this: [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html).

```
In [11]: df  # Note the duplicated row I appended at the end
Out[11]:
   userID locationID
0       1       loc1
1       1       loc2
2       1       loc3
3       2       loc1
4       3       loc4
5       3       loc3
6       3       loc1
7       3       loc1

In [12]: g = df.groupby('locationID')

In [13]: g['userID'].nunique()
Out[13]:
locationID
loc1          3
loc2          1
loc3          2
loc4          1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution:

```
df.groupby(['locID']).size()
```

returns:

```
locID
loc1     3
loc2     1
loc3     2
loc4     1
```

---

#### Try it for yourself:

```
import pandas

txt = '''userID  locationID
 1         loc1 
 1         loc2 
 1         loc3 
 2         loc1 
 3         loc4 
 3         loc3 
 3         loc1'''


listtxt = list(txt.splitlines())
columns = tuple(filter(None, listtxt.pop(0).split()))
vals = [tuple(filter(None, line.split())) for line in listtxt]
df = pandas.DataFrame(vals, columns=columns)
```

`df` now returns:

```
  userID locationID
0      1       loc1
1      1       loc2
2      1       loc3
3      2       loc1
4      3       loc4
5      3       loc3
6      3       loc1
```

and

```
df.groupby(['locationID']).size()
```

returns:

```
locationID
loc1          3
loc2          1
loc3          2
loc4          1
```

Comment: You can just do pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), sep='\s+') to create DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pn

df = pn.DataFrame({'userId': pn.Series([1,1,1,2,3,3,3]),        
                  'locID': pn.Series(['loc1', 'loc2', 'loc3', 'loc1', 'loc4', 'loc3','loc1'])})     
print df.groupby(['locID']).count().userId
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
locID       
loc1        3
loc2        1
loc3        2
loc4        1
```